# Why F-bounded polymorphism and F-bounded quantification are called, well, F-bounded

Tags: terminology, type-theory

It's [claimed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification) in Wikipedia that:

> F-bounded quantification or recursively bounded quantification,
>   introduced in 1989, allows for more precise typing of functions that
>   are applied on recursive types. A recursive type is one that includes
>   a function that uses it as a type for some argument or its return
>   value

Here's [the article](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/99370.99392) which Wikipedia refers to, and F-bounded quantification is introduced in that article in following fashion:

> F-bounded  quantification  is  a  natural  extension  of bounded 
>   quantification  that  seems particularly  useful in  connection  with 
>   recursive  types.

My question is - why though it's F-bounded, what does "F" stands for in this particular context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that "F" does not stand for anything in particular: rather, it is the metavariable symbol that is used in the definition of *F-bounded quantification*. In the paper in which F-bounded quantification was introduced, [*F-Bounded Polymorphism for Object-Oriented Programming*](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/99370.99392), the authors write:

> To solve this problem and related difficulties with other forms of recursive types we introduce a generalization of bounded quantification which we call F-bounded quantification, for want of better terminology.

suggesting that they do not view the name as particularly descriptive. Later, when they define F-bounded quantification explicitly, they write:

> We say that a universally quantified type is F-bounded if it has the form
>   $$\forall t \subseteq F[t] . \sigma$$
>   where $F[t]$ is an expression, generally containing the type variable $t$.

As far as I can tell, the paper contains no other explanation and the most apparent explanation is that the "F" in the terminology is chosen to coincide with the symbol $F$ chosen, arbitrarily, for the definition.

Comment: I see. I just thought that may be F has some well-recognised meaning in this domain, like you know, N or Z, so no additional explanation required.